# devolver Array de peticiones XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome, asincronismo

Estoy desarrollando una extensión para el navegador Chrome.

Cuando se abre una pestaña o se actuliza se le inyecta un content.js (un JavaSCript) mediante chrome.tabs.executeScript a través de un background.js

Lo que hace el content.js es:

- buscar todos los JavaScripts de la nueva pestaña.
- Analizar los scripts.

Para analizar los JavaScripts necesita su contenido.

Si los scripts están incrustados directamente en el HTML ya tiene su contenido.

Si embargo, para los scripts que no están incrustados en el HTML, que tienen un tag "src", por ejemplo, un Jquery externo o local tiene que descargar su contenido.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Para ello utilizo XMLHttpRequest.

Lo que necesito al final es tener el contenido de todos los scripts de la pestaña...
Pero tengo problemas de asincronimos.

```
function getScriptContent(src){
   //Aqui lanzo el XMLHttpRequest.
   ...
}

//Scripts es un Array de scripts de la pestaña
function obtenerContenido(scripts){
     for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            rcScript = scripts[i].src;
            if (srcScript != ""){
                  let content=null;
                  content = getScriptContent(srcScript);
                  if(content==null) continue;
                  //Aquí hago otras cosas.
                  //Finalmente añado el contenido a un array.
             } else {
                  //añado el script inscrustrado al array.
             }

// Al finalizar todo el proceso.
// Envio al background el array completo con todos los scripts y su contenido.
```

Hay varios problemas:
- XMLHttpRequest: Es asícrono por lo que cuando hago el if(content==null) continue siempre se cumple puesto que obtenerContenido() aun no ha obtenido el contenido.

- La ejecución del scripts sugue su camino. Por lo que cuando voy a realizar el envio al background del array con todos los scripts estos aun no se han insertado en el array.
- Para enviar los scripts al background tengo que estar seguro de que se añaden todos los scripts. Tanto los que tengo que descargar su contenido a través de XMLHttpRequest como los que se añaden directamente porque están incrustados en el HTML.

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Un saludo.
¡Muchas gracias!